# How to Export Selected Row On Datatables? I am using Checkbox for selecting datatables row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

1. My server side Code I am trying to export selected rows. after export, it's exporting all records but I wanted to export selected records. For Selection I am using the checkbox

   ```
    while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($queryRecords) )
        { 

                $nestedData=array();
        $nestedData[] = "<input type='checkbox' onclick='checkboxfn($(this));' 
          id='singleBox'  value='". 
                 $index."'/>";
               $nestedData[]  = "<i class='mdi mdi-format-list-bulleted'></i>";
                  $nestedData[]  = $index;
                 $nestedData[] = $row["Designation"];
                 $nestedData[] = $row["CompanyName"];
                 $nestedData[] = $row["PersonalEmail"];
                 $nestedData[] = $row["PersonalPhone"];
                 $nestedData[] = $row["PersonalMobile"];
                $data[] = $nestedData;
                $index++;
         } 

         $json_data = array(
                     "draw"                => 1,  
                     "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalRecords ), 
                       "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalRecords),
                      "data"            => $data   // total data array
                   );
        echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format
   ```
2. This is My Export Button Code. I am able to export all records without selecting any records but I am not able to export selected records

   ```
    dom: 'lBfrtip',

   buttons: [



       {
           extend: 'copyHtml5',

           exportOptions: {
               columns: [6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21 ]
           }
       },
       {
           extend: 'excelHtml5',
           text: 'XLS',
           exportOptions: {
               columns: [6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]
           }
       },
       {
       extend:  'csvHtml5',
       exportOptions: 
       {
           columns: [6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]
       }
       },
       {
           extend: 'pdfHtml5',
           orientation: 'landscape',
       pageSize: 'A0',
           exportOptions: {
               columns: [7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]
           }
       },

    ],


       columnDefs: [{
           "targets": 5,
           "orderable": true,


       }]
   ```
3. My  checkboxfn Function

   ```
       function checkboxfn(t)  
             { 

                if (t.is(':checked')) 
                {
                   var index = rowIds.indexOf(t[0]['value']);  
                       if (index < 0) 
                       {
                           rowIds.push(t[0]['value']);

                       }   

                }else
                {  

                     var index = rowIds.indexOf(t[0]['value']);
                       if (index > -1) {
                           rowIds.splice(index, 1);
                       }            
               }
   ```

Comment: show us the `checkboxfn()` function

Comment: your button export code looks like javascript, and doesnt appear to pass the selected rows anywhere or filter them in any way.

Comment: I Don't think that is an issue maybe we can use columns.render for processing

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found Answer in "buttons.html5.min.js" I have to add Below code

1. For CSV and Copy add following code

   ```
    for(i=0;i<l.length;i++)
         {

        if(rowIds.length != 0)
             {
        // I AM GETTING ERROR ON BELOW LINE
         var index = rowIds.indexOf(l[i].match(/\d+/)[0]);
   console.log("Copy and CSV "+l[i].match(/\d+/)[0]);
   console.log("Index "+index);

   if (index < 0)
   {
       //alert("dont export");
   }
   else
   {

       l[i]=l[i].substr(l[i].indexOf(b.fieldSeparator) + 1);
       temp.push(l[i]);
   }

   }
     else
     {
    //removing the row id from the contact before export.
   l[i]=l[i].substr(l[i].indexOf(b.fieldSeparator) + 1);
   temp.push(l[i]);
     }

    }
   ```
2. And For Excel have to add below code

   ```
    for (var f = 0, h = b.body.length; f < h; f++)

     if(rowIds.length != 0)
      {
     var index = rowIds.indexOf(b.body[f][0]);      
     console.log("Excel "+b.body[f][0]);
       if (index < 0)
       {
           //alert("dont export");
       }
       else
       {
           b.body[f].splice(0, 1);
           a += e(b.body[f]);
       }  
     }
    else
     {
      b.body[f].splice(0, 1);
      a += e(b.body[f]);
     }

    }
   ```